# "Save As" does not seem to work as expected in DRC Sim

Tags: drcsim, gazebo-1.3

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Using **Save As** through the gui of DRC Sim ver. 1.3.1 seems to save the objects in the world using their initial location and orientation. A deleted object will also reappear at its initial location and orientation when the saved world is loaded again.

Steps I took:

1. Opened the sim with an empty world.
2. Added a box to the world.
3. Saved the world, closed the sim, opened the saved world. The box was positioned where I had left it (expected behavior).
4. I moved the box to a new location and changed the orientation (adjusted the yaw value) using the gui.
5. Saved the world as a new world file, closed the sim, opened the newly saved world. The box was positioned in its original location and orientation (not expected behavior).
6. I added a sphere to the world and did not move it. I also moved the box in a similar manner as before.
7. Saved the world as a new world file, closed the sim, opened the newly saved world. The box was positioned in its original location and orientation (not expected behavior). The sphere was there and in its expected location.
8. I deleted the box and moved the sphere to a new location.
9. Saved the world as a new world file, closed the sim, opened the newly saved world. The box was there and was positioned in its original location and orientation (not expected behavior). The sphere was there and in its original location (not expected behavior).

Manually editing the world files (in my favorite text editor) resulted in expected changes including new location/orientation of objects and the addition/removal of objects.

Is this a new issue or is it related to this ticket? https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/346/saving-world-file-does-not-include-changes

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/838/%22save-as%22-does-not-seem-to-work-as-expected-in-drc-sim/) by [david_rusbarsky](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/147/david_rusbarsky/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 111 on 2013-01-15

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Filed a ticket for this: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/787/fix-gui-save-as

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0